# ajax sucess: i can not check if the returned information is true or false

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a problem when I try to check if the returned information is true or false. In console.log returns true but always enters else ...

```
$.ajax({
                    url: "ajax.php",
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: 'act=login&email=' + email + '&password=' + password + '&remember=' + remember,
                    success: function(data) 
                    {
                        console.log(data);
                        if (data.success === true)
                        {
                            $("#login-form")[0].reset();
                            window.location.replace('dashboard.php');
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $(".error-message span").html('Please, insert valid data.');
                            $('.error-message').fadeIn('slow', function () {
                                $('.error-message').delay(5000).fadeOut('slow');
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Thanks everyone.

Comment: whether data is true... or data is an object containing a key success...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Console.log prints `data`.

Your IF statement checks `data.success'. Those are 2 different elements.

In what format are you sending the data back from ajax.php?

You can't assume that data is an array or JSON object, you have to parse it first.

```
json = JSON.parse(data);

if (json.success === true) {} //or if (json === true) depends on the response from ajax.php
```

Per your comment, if you returned data is only true or false, simply use

```
if (data == true) {//I use double and not triple equality because I do not know if you are returning a string or a boolean.
}
```

Your have 2 problems:

1. You are trying to access data.success instead of just data.
2. You are using a strict comparison (===) and I am really not sure if your returned data is boolean and not string. @Pekka's answer mentions it as well (but it's not going to work since data.success does not exist).

Hope this helps!

Comment: my ajax.php returned an echo "true" or "false" and i just whant verify what value is returned...

Comment: so why are trying to access the child (data.success)??

Comment: @user3242861 I revised my answer :)

Comment: resolved. placed well and gave ....

json = JSON.parse(data);
if (json === true)
{...}

Answer (score 0):

The return value is likely to be a string `true` , not a JavaScript boolean `true`.

Because you are using the strict `===` comparison, which requires the same variable type, it will always fail.

Compare against the string:

```
if (data.success == "true")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. i try change the condition but continues to enter else ...

Answer (score 0):

If your data looks like `{"success": true}` then it could be a problem with data parsing where the ajax handler is not parsing the response as a json data.. instead is just passing a string.

So try setting the `dataType` property to `json` to tell ajax that you are expecting a json response.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "ajax.php",
    type: 'POST',
    data: 'act=login&email=' + email + '&password=' + password + '&remember=' + remember,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        if (data.success === true) {
            $("#login-form")[0].reset();
            window.location.replace('dashboard.php');
        } else {
            $(".error-message span").html('Please, insert valid data.');
            $('.error-message').fadeIn('slow', function () {
                $('.error-message').delay(5000).fadeOut('slow');
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ?

> if (data.success == 'true'){......}

or if it comes in "Json" format you need to convert to object like this in "success" event. (included json.js)

> ```
> var JSONfoo = JSON.stringify(data);                           
> obj = eval('(' + JSONfoo + ')');
> if(obj != null){                        
> alert(obj.success );
> ```
>
> }

Answer (score 0):

yesterday in the form that was build the solution `json = JSON.parse (data);` worked, but now another form gives me an error (`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`) on line `json = JSON.parse (data);`

I do not understand the reason for working on a form and not another!

In ajax.php i return an `echo "true";`

thank you all